# How to create a sankey diagram when certain values ​are omitted

Tags: r, data.table, plotly, r-plotly, sankey-diagram

I need to create a sankey diagram in `R` with `plotly` over 3 years. My `group` column should be the nodes (`1` == `worst`, `2` == `bad`, `3` == `good` and `4` == `best`), but however in year 2019 and 2020 I have/need an additional node `5` == `not available`.

My data is very large, so I'll show you just a short snippet of it:

```
dt.2018 <- structure(list(Year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), GPNRPlan = c(100236L, 101554L, 111328L, 
124213L, 127434L, 128509L, 130058L, 130192L, 130224L, 130309L
), TB.Info = c("Below TB", "Over TB", "In TB", "In TB", "In TB", 
"Below TB", "Over TB", "Below TB", "Below TB", "Below TB"), Qeff = c(-0.01, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.01, -0.01), group = c(1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 
2, 1, 4, 2, 3)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

dt.2019 <- structure(list(Year = c(2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L), GPNRPlan = c(100236L, 101554L, 111328L, 
124213L, 127434L, 128003L, 128509L, 130058L, 130192L, 130351L
), TB.Info = c("Below TB", "Over TB", "In TB", "In TB", "In TB", 
"Over TB", "In TB", "Over TB", "Below TB", "Over TB"), Qeff = c(-0.01, 
0.04, -0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), group = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 
1, 1, 3, 2)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

dt.2020 <- structure(list(Year = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L), GPNRPlan = c(100236L, 111328L, 128003L, 
130058L, 130192L, 133874L, 135886L, 137792L, 138153L, 142309L
), TB.Info = c("Below TB", "In TB", "Over TB", "Below TB", "Below TB", 
"Over TB", "Below TB", "Over TB", "Over TB", "In TB"), Qeff = c(0, 
-0.01, 0, 0, -0.01, 0.02, -0.01, -0.01, 0.01, 0), group = c(2, 
3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```

Now I want to see which customers (customer ID == `GPNRPlan`) from **2018** are still in the same group in **2019** or have changed groups and if they are no longer in **2019**, then they should refer to group `5`, also called `not available`. The same should then happen from **2019** to **2020**.
How could this work?

Is it possible to refer from **2018** to **2020** in the same Sankey diagram?

So my sankey diagram for this sample here looks like this (hand-made):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mainly is a question of formatting the data correctly.

I joined the different data.tables to get the NA values.

Furthermore please check the different arrangement options. I don't think your req. output can be achived 100% - either nodes are overlapping, or using "snap" the order of the nodes is changed.

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)
library(scales)

dt.2018 <- structure(list(Year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L),
                          GPNRPlan = c(100236L, 101554L, 111328L, 124213L, 127434L, 128509L, 130058L, 130192L, 130224L, 130309L),
                          TB.Info = c("Below TB", "Over TB", "In TB", "In TB", "In TB", "Below TB", "Over TB", "Below TB", "Below TB", "Below TB"),
                          Qeff = c(-0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.01, -0.01), 
                          group = c(1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3)),
                     class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

dt.2019 <- structure(list(Year = c(2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L), 
                          GPNRPlan = c(100236L, 101554L, 111328L, 124213L, 127434L, 128003L, 128509L, 130058L, 130192L, 130351L), 
                          TB.Info = c("Below TB", "Over TB", "In TB", "In TB", "In TB", "Over TB", "In TB", "Over TB", "Below TB", "Over TB"), 
                          Qeff = c(-0.01, 0.04, -0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                          group = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2)),
                     class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

dt.2020 <- structure(list(Year = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L), 
                          GPNRPlan = c(100236L, 111328L, 128003L, 130058L, 130192L, 133874L, 135886L, 137792L, 138153L, 142309L), 
                          TB.Info = c("Below TB", "In TB", "Over TB", "Below TB", "Below TB", "Over TB", "Below TB", "Over TB", "Over TB", "In TB"), 
                          Qeff = c(0, -0.01, 0, 0, -0.01, 0.02, -0.01, -0.01, 0.01, 0), group = c(2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4)),
                     class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

lookUpDT <- data.table(group = c(as.character(1:4), "NA"), group_name = c("worst", "bad", "good", "best", "not available"), color = c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "darkgrey"))

sankeyDT <- rbindlist(list(merge.data.table(dt.2018, dt.2019, by = "GPNRPlan", all.x = TRUE, suffixes = c(".source", ".target"))[, Year.target := 2019],
merge.data.table(dt.2019, dt.2020, by = "GPNRPlan", all.x = TRUE, suffixes = c(".source", ".target"))[, Year.target := 2020]
))

sankeyDT[, node_id.source := paste0(Year.source, "_", group.source)]
sankeyDT[, node_id.target := paste0(Year.target, "_", group.target)]

charCols <- c("group.source", "group.target")
sankeyDT[,(charCols):= lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = charCols]

sankeyDT <- merge.data.table(sankeyDT, lookUpDT, by.x = "group.source", by.y = "group")

sankeyLabelsDT <- data.table(node_id = sort(unique(c(sankeyDT$node_id.source, sankeyDT$node_id.target)), na.last = TRUE))
sankeyLabelsDT[, c("year", "group") := tstrsplit(node_id, "_", fixed=TRUE)]
sankeyLabelsDT[, x_scale := .GRP, by = year][, y_scale := .GRP, by = group]
sankeyLabelsDT[, x_scale := rescale(x_scale, to=c(0, 0.9))][, y_scale := rescale(y_scale, to=c(0.2, 0.75))]
sankeyLabelsDT <- merge.data.table(sankeyLabelsDT, lookUpDT, by = "group")
sankeyLabelsDT[, label := paste(year, "-", group_name)]
setorder(sankeyLabelsDT, year, group, na.last = TRUE)


fig <- plot_ly(
  data = sankeyDT,
  type = "sankey",
  arrangement = "perpendicular", #  snap - perpendicular - freeform - fixed
  orientation = "h",
  
  node = list(
    label = sankeyLabelsDT$label,
    color = sankeyLabelsDT$color,
    x = sankeyLabelsDT$x_scale,
    y = sankeyLabelsDT$y_scale,
    pad = 10 # 10 Pixel
  ),
  
  link = list(
    source = match(sankeyDT$node_id.source, sankeyLabelsDT$node_id)-1,
    target = match(sankeyDT$node_id.target, sankeyLabelsDT$node_id)-1,
    value =  rep(1, nrow(sankeyDT)),
    label = paste("customer:", sankeyDT$GPNRPlan),
    color = sankeyDT$color # default: grey
  )
)

fig <- fig %>% layout(
  title = "Sankey Diagram",
  font = list(
    size = 10
  )
)

fig
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
That's exactly what I need, but two things are missing:
I need to replace the numbers by: 1==worst, 2==bad, 3 ==good, 4==best and NA=not available
Also I want to have for each equal group (worst, bad, good, best and not available) the same color.

Comment: How can I change the line-width? And in 2020, the the group 4 and NA is the same??

Comment: No - as mentioned in my answer they are overlapping. Change the arrangement parameter for different behaviour,

Comment: Changing the ``arragement`` doesn't change something in the sankey diagram

Comment: Yes it does - change it from "perpendicular" to "snap" and see the difference.

Comment: I changed the colors and the labels - please see my edit. Sorting them according to the y-axis doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: Thank you!
Changing the line-coloring in a specific way is impossible I think, e.g. lines coming from bad are colored orange, lines from worst colored red, and so on ?

Comment: Yes it is possible - you can provide a color argument to `link`. Please see another edit.

Comment: I have another question! I'm using ``snap`` and now my ``2019-best`` is being cut off (below). For all other ``arrangement``s the colors where overlapping

Comment: Yes - that is what I was talking about in the first place - see above `I don't think your req. output can be achived 100%`. You might want to play around with the inputs for `rescale(y_scale, ...)` to find a setup that fits your needs.