# Manipulation of Columns in Data Table (replace, sort)

Tags: r, replace, data.table, data-manipulation

I want to manipulate the columns of two data tables to create a Sankey diagram.
I have one data table for the year `2018` and one for `2019` (both are having the same column names/order):

```
dt.2018 <- structure(list(Year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), 
                          id = c(100236L, 101554L, 111328L, 124213L, 127434L, 128509L, 130058L, 130192L, 130224L, 130309L),
                          EV = c(-33498.61, 0, -31117.17, 70950.43, -37984.99, 0, 0, -93820830.01, -7852622.13, -245712.8), 
                          group = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3"), class = "factor")), 
                         class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

dt.2019 <- structure(list(Year = c(2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L), 
                          id = c(100236L, 101554L, 111328L, 124213L, 127434L, 128003L, 128509L, 130058L, 130192L, 130351L), 
                          EV = c(-130944.64, 21951918.61, 15335.68, 101518.72, 36552.26, 0, 78507.63, 0, 0, 276820967.02), 
                          group = structure(c(1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3"), class = "factor")), 
                         class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

First of all I want to compare the `id` columns.

1. `id`s of `dt.2019`, which are not in `dt.2018` can be deleted (whole row).
2. For `id`s of `dt.2018`, which are not in `dt.2019` we have to copy/rbind the whole row into `dt.2019` and replace then the number of `group` by `8` in `dt.2019`.
3. In the end I want to sort the `id` columns of both (same `id` has to be at same row-index).
4. Replace `group` integers in `dt.2019`: replace `c(0,1,2,3)` by `c(4,5,6,7)` and `8` should stay the same.

How can I do this in a fast and efficient way?

Comment: For future readers: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68906156/how-to-create-a-sankey-diagram-when-certain-values-are-omitted) you can find a related / previous question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditions were pretty complicated for me to understand,
so please tell me if this code does not match with your purpose.

```
    dt.2019 %>%
      filter(id %in% dt.2018$id) %>%
      mutate(group = recode_factor(group, "0" = "4", "1" = "5", "2" ="6", "3" ="7")) %>%
      rbind(dt.2018 %>%
              filter(! id %in% dt.2019$id) %>%
              mutate(group = 8)) %>%
      arrange(id)
```

Comment: This is precisely how I was doing it too. Just one difference, instead of ```rbind``` I was using ```bind_rows```

Answer (score 2):

We could do this with a combination of `semi_join` and `anti_join` and `bind_rows` and `reocde_factor` all in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

dt.2019 %>% 
  semi_join(dt.2018, by="id") %>% 
  mutate(group = recode_factor(group, "0" = "4", "1" = "5", "2" ="6", "3" ="7")) %>% 
  bind_rows(dt.2018 %>% 
              anti_join(dt.2019, by="id") %>% 
              mutate(group=8, group=as.factor(group))
            )
```

output:

```
    Year     id          EV group
 1: 2019 100236  -130944.64     4
 2: 2019 101554 21951918.61     7
 3: 2019 111328    15335.68     4
 4: 2019 124213   101518.72     5
 5: 2019 127434    36552.26     5
 6: 2019 128509    78507.63     5
 7: 2019 130058        0.00     5
 8: 2019 130192        0.00     5
 9: 2018 130224 -7852622.13     8
10: 2018 130309  -245712.80     8
```